mathjax not working in html display incorrect output
html header script tag
<script id="MathJax-script" async="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

in python file i am adding the text to html
html+='<span class="math">'+'\['+item['text']+'\]'+'</span>'

I am using below samples
"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{\\\\ln(0.917)}{\\\\sqrt{\\\\pi^2 + [\\\\ln(0.917)\\\\]^2}}\\\\"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{-0.085}{\\\\sqrt{\\\\pi^2 + (-0.085)^2}}"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{-0.085}{\\\\sqrt{\\\\pi^2 + 0.007225}}"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{-0.085}{\\\\sqrt{9.8696 + 0.007225}}\\\\"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{-0.085}{\\\\sqrt{9.876825}}\\\\"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx \\\\frac{-0.085}{3.14444}\\\\"

"text": "\\\\zeta_1 \\\\approx -0.027\\\\"


